# HDMI video stream

Tags: hdmi, pcm

I am trying to determine the format of the audio portion of a video being sent from a digital device (DVD player, DVR, etc.) to a digital TV via an HDMI cable.  My understanding is that the audio portion of this video is converted to a standard uncompressed PCM format.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. HDMI devices supporting audio transmission MUST support 2-channel L-PCM but there are a variety of other optional audio formats allowed by the HDMI 1.4b specification.

Comment: Ok, but the bottom line is that all HDMI devices MUST support LPCM, correct?  thanks!

Comment: @Bcorngtr, yes, if the device supports any audio formats, LPCM must be one of them.

Answer (score 0):

It must support uncompressed PCM, yes

> Audio data, which can consist of any compressed, non-compressed, PCM,
>   single or multi-channel formats (including the new DTS-HD Master Audio
>   and Dolby TrueHD formats for blue laser DVDs), fit into the video
>   blanking intervals and are sent as HDMI packets.

[source page 10](http://www.hdmi.org/pdf/whitepaper/SilicaonImageHDMIWhitePaperv73%282%29.pdf)

> For digital audio, if an HDMI device supports audio, it is required to
>   support the baseline format: stereo (uncompressed) PCM. Other formats
>   are optional, with HDMI allowing up to 8 channels of uncompressed
>   audio at sample sizes of 16-bit, 20-bit and 24-bit, with sample rates
>   of 32 kHz, 44.1 kHz, 48 kHz, 88.2 kHz, 96 kHz, 176.4 kHz and 192 kHz.

from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Audio.2Fvideo)